# Google Form : Allow ONLY one response each day

Tags: google-forms

I want to allow each user ONLY one response **each** day.
i.e After login i submit the form, it shouldnt allow me second response today, which is possible easily, but it should be allow 2nd response tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that Google Forms has any feature like that.

One option might be to ask respondents for their email address (or some other identifier) and only to accept the first entry (ie the one with the minimum date/time) each day.